# How does Pandas.read_csv type casting work?

Tags: python, pandas

Using `pandas.read_csv` with `parse_dates` option and a custom date parser, I find Pandas has a mind of its own about the  data type it's reading.

Sample csv:

```
"birth_date", "name"
"","Dr. Who"
"1625", "Rembrandt"
"1533", "Michel"
```

The actual datecleaner is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200179/39869), but what I do boils down to this:

```
import pandas as pd

def dateclean(date):
    return str(int(date)) # Note: we return A STRING

df = pd.read_csv(
        'my.csv', 
        parse_dates=['birth_date'],
        date_parser=dateclean, 
        engine='python'
        )

print(df.birth_date)
```

Output:

```
0       NaN
1    1625.0
2    1533.0
Name: birth_date, dtype: float64
```

I get type `float64`, *even* when I specified `str`. Also, take out the first line in the CSV, the one with the empty birth_date, and I get type `int`. The workaround is easy:

```
return '"{}"'.format(int(date))
```

Is there a better way?

In data analysis, I can imagine it's useful that Pandas will say 'Hey dude, you thought you were reading strings, but in fact they're numbers'. But what's the rationale for overruling me when I tell it not to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `parse_dates` / `date_parser` looks a bit complicated for me, unless you want to generalise your import on many date columns. I think you have more control with `converters` parameter, where you can fit `dateclean()` function. You can also experiment with `dtype` parameter.

The problem with original `dateclean()` function is that it fails on `""` value, because `int("")` raises `ValueError`. Pandas seem to resort to standard import when it encounters this problem, but it will fail explicitly with `converters`.

Below is the code to demonstrate a fix:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

doc = """"birth_date", "name"
"","Dr. Who"
"1625", "Rembrandt"
"1533", "Michel"
"""

Path('my.csv').write_text(doc)

def dateclean(date):
    try: 
       return str(int(date)) 
    except ValueError:
       return '' 

df = pd.read_csv(
        'my.csv', 
        parse_dates=['birth_date'],
        date_parser=dateclean, 
        engine='python'
        )

df2 = pd.read_csv(
        'my.csv', 
        converters = {'birth_date': dateclean}
        )

print(df2.birth_date)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "unless you want to generalise your import on many date columns", yes, there are  four of them.

Comment: I think you are still better off with `converters` as they behave more explicitly and your dates are just years + you also seem to want string type for those columns.

Comment: I totally agree, all four date columns are quite inconsistent, so I used `converter` for all four.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `date_parser` is designed specifically for conversion to `datetime`:

> **date_parser** : *function, default None*
> Function to use for converting a sequence of string columns to an array of datetime
>   instances.

There is no reason you should *expect* this parameter to work for other types. Instead, you can use the `converters` parameter. Here we use [`toolz.compose`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.compose) to apply `int` and then `str`. Alternatively, you can use `lambda x: str(int(x))`.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from toolz import compose

mystr = StringIO('''"birth_date", "name"
"","Dr. Who"
"1625", "Rembrandt"
"1533", "Michel"''')

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, 
                 converters={'birth_date': compose(str, int)},
                 engine='python')

print(df.birth_date)       

0     NaN
1    1625
2    1533
Name: birth_date, dtype: object
```

If you need to replace `NaN` with empty strings, you can post-process with `fillna`:

```
print(df.birth_date.fillna(''))       

0        
1    1625
2    1533
Name: birth_date, dtype: object
```

Comment: `lambda x: str(int(x))` will fail on empty string

Comment: @Evgeny, Actually, I see `NaN` (as in my example). That may or may not be what OP wants. For a true fallback, you would need to check for an empty string, or post-process. Have updated with the second idea.

Comment: Not really a question of masking a `NaN` - your code works fine with `toolz.compose()`, but if you put `lambda x: str(int(x))` as suggested in side comment - your are getting ValueError on import.

Comment: @Evgeny, I tested with `lambda` too. Works without error on Pandas 0.19.2 [admittedly an old version] / Python 3.6.0.

Comment: strange, failed on me with ValueError

Comment: ```File ..., line 40, in <lambda>
    converters = {'birth_date': lambda x: str(int(x))}

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''```

Comment: Could it be pandas treat ValueError on import differently in different versions?

Comment: @Evgeny, Maybe, can't test though :S. But I like `compose` better anyway :)

Comment: `toolz` looks like a nice functional library, thanks for pointing!